# Using a dynamic cell reference for find/replace in a macro (without VBA)

Tags: dynamic, replace, macros, find

I'd be very grateful if someone can help.

I have a fair number of formulas that point to external workbooks, and these need to be updated to new workbooks whenever new data is produced.

This can be done with a simple Find/Replace to change the name of the workbook that the formula points to, but I was hoping to hook it up to a macro button so my colleagues can update it easily without me.

Essentially what I want to do is have a cell (A1, for instance) where you enter in the old address, a cell (A2) where you enter in the new address, and then a button that starts the macro whereby it 'Finds' A1 and 'Replaces' it with A2.

I've put all this together and recorded a macro (copying the contents of A1 and A2 into the Find/Replace tool), and it worked well in the first instance.  However, when I updated it with a new workbook reference, it didn't do anything.  Debugging showed that it had literally taken the text of A1 and A2 and hard coded that into the macro, rather than following through with the steps of copying the (changed) text from A1 and A2.  So, for instance, it was always updating January to February, and would never update February to March.

Is there any way - without VBA - to have the macro understand that the contents of A1 and A2 may change each time, so that it retrieves it each time rather than just in the first instance?

(Incidentally, I'm aware that the new workbook needs to be open at the time the macro runs, or else it won't work).

Many thanks,

Kelly

Comment: I was about to change your [macros] tag to [excel-vba], because the [macros] tag is inappropriate when talking about VBA.  Then I noticed you specifically say you don't want to use VBA. So what are you referring to when you talk about "macros"??  The only think I can think of is the really old-style macro-sheets - is that what you are trying to use?  Maybe if you show your current (non-VBA) macro, we might be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply.  By 'macro', I mean the function on the View ribbon whereby you can record Macros that you can run later either by using an assigned hotkey or clicking a button that they've been hooked up to.
Going into the edit section for my Macro, here's the code:

(Looks like I may have to post it in sections, as there's a fairly low word limit on replies)

Comment: Sub Update_This_Sheet()
'
' Update_This_Sheet Macro
'

'
    Range("B63").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "(folder address)...\export\[TAB_2_2_ENG.csv]TAB_2_2_ENG"
    Range("B64").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "(folder address)...\export\[TAB_2_2_WAL.csv]TAB_2_2_WAL"
    Rows("22:31").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Selection.Replace What:= _
        "(folder address)...\export\[TAB_2_2_ENG.csv]TAB_2_2_ENG" _
        , Replacement:= _
        "(folder address)...\export\[TAB_2_2_WAL.csv]TAB_2_2_WAL" _

Comment: , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
        :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Range("A61").Select
End Sub


Please note, I've cut out the full folder address and replaced it with (folder address)... just for brevity, leaving only the end section which has the part I want to Find/Replace.

Cheers,

  Kelly